# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Error in Lynda Rails Training (Ch 9 - Delete/Destroy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new, so forgive my complete ignorance. I'm on Rails 3.2.3 and am doing the Lynda Ruby on Rails Essentials course. I've completed the chapter listed in the title, but am getting an error page after confirming the delete button. Here is a video to show you the [error in action](http://screencast.com/t/0a1d3gUxyZ).

I've reviewed the following docs to confirm that I've not made typing errors.

Here is my list.html.erb

```
<div class="subject list">
<h2>Subjects</h2>

<%= link_to("Add New Subject", {:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new') %>

<table class="listing" summary="Subject List">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Visible</th>
        <th>Pages</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= subject.position %></td>
        <td><%= subject.name %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
        <td class="actions">
            <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
            <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action edit') %>
            <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action delete') %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Here is my delete.html.erb

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subject delete">
    <h2>Delete Subject</h2>

<%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'destroy'}, :id => @subject.id) do |f| %>

    <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this subject?</p>

    <p class="reference-name">Subject name: <%= @subject.name %></p>

    <div class ="form-buttons">
        <%= submit_tag("Delete Subject") %>
        </div>

    <% end %>


</div>
```

Here is my subjects_controller.rb

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    list
    render('list')
end


def list
    @subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")
  end

  def show
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @subject = Subject.new
  end

  def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
    @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])
    # Save the object
    if @subject.save
      # If save succeeds, redirect to the list action
      redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
     @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
     # Find object using form parameters
      @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
      # Update the object
      if @subject.update_attributes(params[:subject])
        # If save succeeds, redirect to the list action
        redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @subject.id)
      else
        # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
        render('edit')
      end
  end

  def delete
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
     Subject.find(params[:id]).destroy
     redirect_to(:action => 'list')
  end
end
```

Here is the [resulting error page](http://screencast.com/t/lngHci1gR) referenced in the video above.

If I can get some help in understanding why I can't get this properly delete the file, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I have never heard of "Lynda Ruby on Rails Essentials course" but I can see from your posted code that your delete form looks totally messed up, you have a form_for but you are using a submit_tag! That doesn't make sense. The problem is that if you look in your log file you will see that the params passed in to the delete action do not include an id therefore when you use `@subject = Subject.find(params[:id])` you will get the error you are seeing.

The solution - change the submit_tag to f.submit OR change the form_for to a form_tag and make sure the correct route is called, that way the id should be passed back through the params hash.

Your log file stack trace is ALWAYS your very best friend, learn to understand it ASAP and you will find your life a lot easier.

**UPDATE**

For a large number of reasons I think your best option would be to change your form to look like this

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subject delete">
    <h2>Delete Subject</h2>


    <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this subject?</p>

    <p class="reference-name">Subject name: <%= @subject.name %></p>

    <div class ="form-buttons">
        <%= button_to "Delete", subject_path(@subject), method: :delete %>
    </div>

</div>
```

The reason the first way did not work is because you missed the leading opening tag "<" which is why the text got displayed instead of the button

you don't need the form, you are entering no data so just use the button_to and tell it to go to the delete action.

I haven't tested the code but it should be fine

Comment: James, I tried the 1st option and when the delete.html page loaded the button was gone and replaced with the text "%= f.submit("Delete Subject") %>".
On the second option, I got a result error page "NoMethodError in Subjects#delete". 
It could be that the "correct route was not called", but I'm not sure what that means. Lynda.com is an online training course but it uses an older version of Rails, which I think may be causing some of the problems. I've made sure to put the code in exactly as they have.

Comment: @BrettPayne I have updated my answer. Can I suggest you get hold of a copy of AWDWR (Agile Web Development With Rails). It is the bible for most Rails developers and explains this very clearly. you should at least get the pdf which can be obtained from http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails